# Why is YUM showing that is installing MariaDB instead of MySQL on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum

I just created medium size EC2 and ran command in it:

`sudo yum install mysql -y`

This is what is showing up:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.52-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 8.6 M
Installed size: 49 M
Downloading packages:
mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                    | 8.6 MB  00:00:01
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : 1:mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            1/1
  Verifying  : 1:mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                           1/1

Installed:
  mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.52-1.el7

Complete!
```

Is this expected? I thought will see MySql packages ONLY. What is the relation between MariaDB and MySQL?

Comment: Several Linux distributions use maria as the default instead of MySQL. You can add the MySQL repository and use that instead of you prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yh, it's completely fine.

To put it simply, MySQL is not MariaDB - as MariaDB is a [Drop in replacement for MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/).

---

> MariaDB is a [backward compatible, binary drop-in replacement of
>   MySQL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql). What this means is:
>
> - Data and table definition files (.frm) files are binary compatible.
> - All client APIs, protocols and structs are identical.
> - All filenames, binaries, paths, ports, sockets, and etc... should be the same.
> - All MySQL connectors work unchanged with MariaDB.
> - The mysql-client package also works with MariaDB server.
>
> In most common practical scenarios, MariaDB version 5.x.y will work
>   exactly like MySQL 5.x.y, MariaDB follows the version of MySQL, i.e.
>   it's version number is used to indicate with which MySQL version it's
>   compatible.

---

Edit 1: In apropos of comment

> why this command does not work? `sudo yum install mysql-server` 
>   Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos 
>   **No package mysql-server available**.

By default MariaDB is supported - to install mysql-server you need to add it using RPM:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Once added, now you can install it:

```
yum -y install mysql-community-server
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know by the way why this command does not work?
`sudo yum install mysql-server`  
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
   
`No package mysql-server available.`
Should REPL be added or?

Comment: CentOS et al, by default support MariaDB, to install mysql-server first you have to add it using rpm

Answer (score 1):

It is just because mysql is owned by oracle now, so the author of mysql created a new branch of mysql and named it mariadb.Now it is maintained by opensource community and is backward-compatible. I think there are not many differences between the two.